# How to print a specific item from List

Tags: c#, list

I'm trying to make a phonebook app (still a beginner at c#). One option is 'View Contact' where the user types a name, resulting in that name along with its number to be printed. Really need some help figuring this out. Here's my code:

```
public class ContactsList
{
    public string contactName { get; set; }
    public int contactNumber { get; set; }

    public List<ContactsList> listMethod()
    {
        List<ContactsList> contacts = new List<ContactsList>();
        {
            contacts.Add(new ContactsList { contactName = "John", contactNumber = 01 });
            contacts.Add(new ContactsList { contactName = "Jack", contactNumber = 02 });
            contacts.Add(new ContactsList { contactName = "Jay", contactNumber = 03 });
        }

        return contacts;
    }
```

Above is the Class which contains my list of contacts. Below is the class where I'm trying the 'ViewContact' method.

```
class AppOptions
{
    ContactsList contactList = new ContactsList();

    public void viewContact()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("       View Contact:");
        Console.WriteLine("       -------------");
        Console.WriteLine("Select contact");
        string userChoice = Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Need to know what to now put after the last bit of code above.
So for eg, if user types "Jay" it should print "Jay" and "03".

Comment: Try `ContactsList contact = contacts.Where(contact => contact.contactName == userChoice).FIrstOrDefault();`.

Comment: What should happen if there is more than one contact with the name "Jay"?

Comment: @Enigmativity or `contacts.FirstOrDefault(c => c.contactName == userChoice)` (simplifying `.Where(...).FirstOrDefault()`)

Comment: @Rafalon - I take the opposite opinion that the two method approach simplifies readability and refactorability. I feel that there is very little benefit in simplifying.

Comment: OT as ContactNumber is an int, leading zeroes are ignored (03 is identical to 3)

Answer (score 3):

Look through the list and when you find the user, print them out. This code should go after the point where you ask the user for their choice

```
foreach(var c in contactList){
  if(userChoice.Equals(c.contactName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    Console.WriteLine(c.contactName + " " + c.contactNumber);
}
```

I've avoided use of LINQ because this seems like an academic exercise at a level that doesn't make me immediately feel that it will have been taught. I've also made the name checking case insensitive. If there are multiple people with the same name they will all print out. If you want partial name matching, consider Contains instead of Equals (contactName Contains userChoice - swap the order around. You'll also have to bear in mind, if you do swap it round, that your list could contain a null name which will cause an error, but it's easy to add handling for that case (check it is not null first before you call Equals/Contains on it))

There are some other things to brush up on in your code - public properties are named with PascalCase not camelCase. Also your ContactList class should probably just be called Contact because it is not a list

Answer (score 2):

I have refactored your code into a more idiomatic c# approach.

Here it is:

```
public class Contact
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
}

public class AppOptions
{
    public void ViewContact()
    {
        List<Contact> contacts = new List<Contact>()
        {
            new Contact { Name = "John", Number = 1 },
            new Contact { Name = "Jack", Number = 2 },
            new Contact { Name = "Jay", Number = 3 },
        };
        
        Console.WriteLine("       View Contact:");
        Console.WriteLine("       -------------");
        Console.WriteLine("Select contact");
        
        string userChoice = Console.ReadLine();
        
        Contact contact = contacts.Where(c => c.Name == userChoice).FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

Typically you don't mix the class with the definition of the list. Also you are using non-standard casing with your method naming.

Comment: I know that's from OP's original code, but the `contacts` initialization feels weird to me (those `contacts.Add` inside brackets). Should work though. Also good point for changing the class name from `ContactsList` to `Contact` (as it really doesn't look like a contact's list)

Comment: @Rafalon - Oh, yes. I don't how I didn't notice that. The code ran fine. It's legal, but weird. I'll fix it.

Comment: It technically doesn't make a difference, but `FirstOrDefault` has an overload which takes a `Func<TSource, Boolean>` which you can use to replace the call to `Where` here. This would turn the last line into this `Contact contact = contacts.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Name == userChoice);`

Comment: @MindSwipe this is what I commented under the question itself, but Enigmativity opposed a point to that, which stands too